# click backspace button long then word count not getting refreshed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#desc_user").on('keyup', function() {
  var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
  if (words > 50) {
    var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 50).join(" ");
    $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
  } else {
    $('#word_left').text(50 - words);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm description_notes errorAddDesc" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your text" id="desc_user" name="desc_user"></textarea><br>
<span id="word_left">50</span>
```

***Below is my url for word count once we press key up.***

It's not working when we press the long backspace button i tried to get word count, but when i press long backspace button it's not getting refreshed.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramumothukuri/d3on18wj/)

[image: before long press backspace]
[image: after long press backspace goes to 48 instead of 50]

Comment: Please use a StackOverflow snippet and fix your post.

Comment: @sjahan please check i have posted the code, please help me this

Comment: The console clearly shows the error that occurs in that situation, so what more do you need?

Comment: Also try using `input` event if you are asking about holding the backspace button down

Comment: @CBroe i have attached the screen shot please check, after long pres it shows wrong count. 48 showing after logn press instead of 50

Comment: I don’t need a screenshot, I have understood what your problem is. I want to know from _you_ what your problem is with understanding the error message it shows in the console …?

Comment: @CBroe Showing error : Can not read property(this.value is empty) is it correct

Comment: You are trying to access the `length` property of an object that doesn’t have one - because when the textarea is completely empty, your `match(/\S+/g)` only returns `null` - in an empty string there are no non-whitespace characters to match. You’d get the same error right away, if the first character you type in is a whitespace character to begin with. So you need to check if match returned an actual object, before you try to access its length property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking whether textarea has value before counting word will be the solution for your problem here.

```js
$("#desc_user").on('keyup', function() {
  var words;
  if (this.value)
    words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
  else
    words = 0;

  if (words > 50) {

    // Split the string on first 50 words and rejoin on spaces
    var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 50).join(" ");
    // Add a space at the end to keep new typing making new words
    $(this).val(trimmed + " ");

  } else {
    $('#word_left').text(50 - words);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea autocomplete="off" class="form-control input-sm description_notes errorAddDesc" type="text" placeholder="Please enter your text" id="desc_user" name="desc_user"></textarea><br>
<span id="word_left">50</span>
```